# GRUB error (2) while booting Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, grub2, boot-failure

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer. The install went fine but now I have the next error while booting: `grub stage 1.5 - error 2`

I'm posting from the live CD and I didn't find an useful answer in Google.

Comment: Adding the output of the boot info script to your question would help, but stage1.5 is part of grub-legacy and 12.04 uses grub2, so you must have some other disk that has an old broken grub install on it that you are booting rather than the one you installed 12.04 on.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I understand what you wrote, but I'm a newbie with Ubuntu. Where is this boot info script ? I didn't find it. Before installing Ubuntu I was running Kubuntu (don't remember the version). Maybe am I still lauching the old grub... But how to check it ? I tried "sudo grub" on my Live cd, but i get a "command not found"...

Comment: Google for boot info script and it should be the first thing that comes up.  Do you have more than one hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

Boot from LiveCD and from a terminal run 'grub-install /dev/hda' command and then boot from the hard disk. The command will do a fresh install of grub on your hard disk and overwrite any previous versions of grub. Hopefully this will fix it.